# Trying to split a file into four pieces, without splitting up sequences

Tags: split, grep, rna-seq

I have a large file containing a number of sequences, each prefaced with `>MSTRG`, which I need to split into four to run a tool on them. When I use `$ split -b [desired file size] [output prefix]` or when I use the `-l` option it splits it into pieces of the desired size. However, it does so indiscriminately, which leads to broken sequences.

Is there a way to use `split` and `grep` together, splitting the files once a 1/4 of the `>MSTRG` matches have been made?

Comment: Try using **GNU Parallel** with `parallel --pipe -j4 --recstart '>MSTRG' 'cat > {#}.txt' < bigfile`

Answer (score 0):

```
parallel --recstart '>MSTRG' # Make records start with '>MSTRG'
         --recend '\n'       # and end with newline (so "foo>MSTRG" is ignored)
         -a bigfile          # Use bigfile as input
         --pipepart          # Efficiently pipe blocks of data into a program (faster than --pipe)
         -j4                 # Run 4 jobs in parallel
         --block -1          # Divide into one block per running job (i.e. 1/4 of bigfile size)
         'cat > {#}.out'     # save output into 1..4.out
```

GNU Parallel will compute the number of jobs to run in parallel (4) and the size of bigfile (bigsize). Then it will compute a block size as bigsize/4. Then it will look for regend+regstart around the position of n*bigsize/4. And when it finds a full record, it will split at that record.

If the goal is to run the same program on each of the 4 output files, you can often replace `cat` with that program. This way you can completely avoid the step of having these temporary split files. If your program cannot read from stdin (standard input), then have a look at `--cat` or `--pipe`. They are built for that situation.